# Wordpress thumbnails not working AWS EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, thumbnails

I have a website that I'm working on - I've been staging it while I was waiting to get the server access from the client.

Now we've gotten server access and they are using Amazon Web Services -Ubuntu.  I am  very new to this AWS service - but my issue is that my thumbnails are no longer working when I do a search

[This is what I want, and had on the staging server](http://freelunchscreenprinting.com/testsite/?s=bread&x=0&y=0), displaying 'feature image' thumbnails in search results

[this is on the AWS server](http://learn.rupertport.com/?s=this+is&x=0&y=0), no thumbnails.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be happening?  Do I have to contact AWS to set something differently?  Can I set it myself?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. It looks like the thumbnail files aren't created (filename-[dimension].jpg)
You should install php-gd to solve this `sudo yum install php-gd`

Comment: I am a true novice at using the terminal,  I put in > ssh & ##.###.###.### (IP)
it gave me >> Permission denied (publickey).
   
there is a privacy key that I have been given - can anyone walk me through the process just a bit?

Comment: This worked for me on the AWS Amazon Linux AMI. (php53-gd or php5-gd as mentioned elsewhere weren't found in the repos.) Installing php-gd and restarting `httpd` did the trick for me. See http://posts.phillipcalvin.com/post/271771136/wordpress-secretly-requires-php-gd. Will only work for new images unless you use a regenerate thumbnails plugin.

Answer (score 1):

your `img` tags don't have a value in the src attribute

```
<img src="" class="post-thumb" alt="this is a post" width="186" height="186">
```

Comment: ...But it should be there - it should display just like the staged site. I've gotten some updated information - I've been told to add a GD image library on the new server, but I'm not sure where to add that.  So I'm looking into that

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Wordpress requires PHP 5.2 or higher. So you will need to install the latest version of php53-gd:

```
sudo yum install php53-gd
```